# Securing my HTTP connections

Tags: node.js, http, https, arduino, jwt

I am currently working on a Home Automation project. The following is my setup.

> A ESP8266 WiFi module will be connected to various sensors. A light
>   web server will be running on the module. There will be a Linode Cloud
>   deployed running certain NodeJS scripts and MongoDB database. The
>   mobile application(Client) will be sending requests to cloud to
>   control and monitor various sensors. I will be securing the connection
>   between the application and cloud using JSON Web Tokens. Also I will
>   try to use HTTPS to secure this connection.

I am confused on how to secure the communication between the Cloud server and the ESP8266 module. I did a lot of research. Got to know certain concepts but could not get a clear and complete picture. Someone please guide me. Thank You.

Comment: your three best options: https. https. https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a token in headers between all you apps.
And when you send request, this will look something like this:

```
request.post({
  url: 'https://mycoolserver.com/',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'lalalablablabla'
  }
})
```

**UPDATE:** As far as you send request, the server on that side checks if your token matches the one he has. There are a lot of security tricks to keep you tokens safe, this one I suggested, is very basic security, but you can do it easily just on flight. Later on you can increase your security level.

Comment: Sorry if my question sounds senseless... but can this token in header be tapped by any intruder? Or is it secure? If not, how do I make it secure?

Comment: this is not safe at all, anyone can see the token, which seems to never change...

Comment: how you see, we are talking about server-server communication, right?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a real time clock in both system (Client and Server)

Generate a function something like `(((unixTime)/1000) + SomeNumbers) * ASmallNumber` Where `(unixTime)/1000 is unixTime in second`, `SomeNumbers is a static number like 897645`, `ASmallNumber is a small number like 7`

This formula will generate a number depends on time. Send this number to the receiver. In receiver (with same `SomeNumbers` and `ASmallNumber` value), decode the number and check unixTime using receiver unixTime

example: if (unixTime - decodedUnixTime < 5 && unixTime - decodedUnixTime >0) then message is trusted

Comment: this is trivial to bypass, so it's not worth the effort of implementing.